# valid F1 visa but expired I20

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, student-visas

I was an F1 student in the USA till July 2022, I then decided to travel to south America for a while. Can I still transit through US if I have a valid f1 visa but my I20 has expired?

Answer (score 3):

No. You can only enter the US on an F1 visa if you are entering the US to engage in studies (or other F1 purpose like OPT).